# What haftarah is read on Shabbat Rosh Chodesh Av

Tags: minhag, rosh-chodesh-new-month, nine-days, haftarah, three-weeks

On the middle *shabbat* of the ‘Three Weeks’, Ashkenazi and Sefaradi practice is to read a *haftarah* starting from [Jeremiah 2:4](https://mechon-mamre.org/p/pt/pt1102.htm#4).

What happens in the (somewhat rare) case that this *shabbat* is also Rosh Chodesh Av? Is the *haftarah* for the Three Weeks still read, or is it superseded by the regular *haftarah* for *shabbat rosh chodesh* from [Isaiah 66](https://mechon-mamre.org/p/pt/pt1066.htm)?

Additionally, [Megillah 31b](https://www.sefaria.org.il/Megillah.31a.19?lang=bi) quotes Rav Huna as saying that the *haftarah* for such a *shabbat* includes [Isaiah 1:14](https://mechon-mamre.org/p/pt/pt1001.htm#14). Does anyone follow this practice?

Comment: https://he.wikisource.org/wiki/%D7%A9%D7%95%D7%9C%D7%97%D7%9F_%D7%A2%D7%A8%D7%95%D7%9A_%D7%90%D7%95%D7%A8%D7%97_%D7%97%D7%99%D7%99%D7%9D_%D7%AA%D7%9B%D7%94_%D7%90

Comment: [Some] Yemenites follow Rav Huna IINM

Comment: When rosh chodesh overrides reeh, many push if off to combine it with the adjacent ki tetzei. Why don't we find the same phenomenon with people reading a double haftara the week before rosh chodesh av?

Comment: @DoubleAA אקדומי פורעונתא לא מקדמינן?

Comment: clever! I'm a bit skeptical still

Comment: @DoubleAA do those Teimanim specifically do that for RC Av, or do they always read Chazon on the 2nd shabbat of bein hametzarim?

Comment: https://oukosher.org/halacha-yomis/because-there-is-a-convergence-this-shabbos-of-rosh-chodesh-with-the-2nd-shabbos-of-the-three-weeks-an-interesting-question-presents-itself-which-haftorah-should-be-read-should-it-be-the-haftorah-o/?category

Comment: https://hakirah.org/Vol%206%20Rabinowich.pdf

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From an Ashkenazi perspective, [Kitzur Shulchan Aruch 122:6](https://www.sefaria.org/Kitzur_Shulchan_Arukh.122.6?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en) writes both customs exist

> On the three Shabbosos between the seventeenth of Tammuz and Tishah
> beAv, we read the "Three haftaros of retribution," which are: [...]
> Shim'u devar Hashem, (Hear the word of Hashem) (Jeremiah 2:4) [...] If
> Rosh Chodesh Av occurs on Shabbos, he reads the haftarah [normally
> read on Rosh Hodesh] Hashamayim Kis'i (The heaven is My throne)
> (Isaiah 66), but in some communities, the haftarah Shim'u is read.

Rema ([SA OC 425:1](https://www.sefaria.org/Shulchan_Arukh%2C_Orach_Chayim.425.1?lang=bi)) mentions both customs, *Shim'u* (Abudharam, Mordekhi) *v' yesh omrim* *Hashamayim Kis'i*.

Artscroll's *humash* has *Shim'u devar Hashem* while noting "some congregations read the Haftara for Rosh Hodesh". Koren's *humash* and *Tanakh* give *Shim'u devar Hashem* for parasha Masei without noting a different haftara for Shabbat Rosh Hodesh.

I also consulted the "*[luach dinim u'minagim kminhag edot Israel](http://www.daat.ac.il/daat/vl/5770dinim/5770dinim01.pdf)*" (see p. 76) from [Heichal Shlomo](https://hechalshlomo.org.il) which is the standard calendar used by national religious synagogues in Israel. It has *Shim'u devar Hashem* as the haftara but adds that some also say the first and last verse of the Rosh Hodesh haftara.

**I found** (in R Chaim Drukman's book [Step by step](https://machon.oretzion.com/document/step%20by%20step%20example.pdf)) **one possible reason that might explain why we should read a "haftara of punishment" even if Rosh Hodesh falls on Shabbat.** Abudraham ([here](https://www.sefaria.org/Abudarham%2C_Hebrew_Calendar%2C_Order_of_Parashiot_and_Haftarot.59?lang=en&with=all&lang2=en)) writes the sequence of the seven Haftarot of consolation is a running conversation between God, the prophets and Knesset Israel. As such one should not "interrupt the conversation" by reading haftara Rosh Hodesh in the middle. Possibly the same idea applies to the haftarot before 9 Av.

---

On your last question re R Huna, Artscroll's gemara Megila 31b notes that "we" do not follow the Gemara in this instance, as we follow the opinion to start the heavier mourning for 9 Av during the week that it falls in and not (as in Rav Huna's view) from Rosh Hodesh Av. As such we do not read Isaiah 1:14 on Rosh Hodesh Av but on the Shabbat immediately preceding 9 Av.

Comment: The Yekke seem to go with the second option (see p. 68 [here](https://www.moreshesashkenaz.org/mm/publications/LuachMinhagim.pdf)): מפטירים 'שמעו דבר ה' עד 'אלוף נעורי אתה', אף כי חל בראש חודש. I've found the same opinion in my Hungarian luach as well.

Comment: Aruch Hashulchan reports that in Lithuania and Pozen they would read the haftara for rosh chodesh ראש חודש אב שחל בשבת – יש אומרים דשל ראש חודש נדחית, ויש אומרים ד"שמעו" נדחית, וקורין "השמים כסאי". וכן עיקר לדינא במקום שאין מנהג להיפך. וכן נהגו בפוזנא, וכן אנו נוהגים מפני שכן עיקר With the Rama endorsing it in his Mappa as well it seems clear this was the dominant eastern ashkenazi minhag, unlike what Koren presents

Comment: Here's a detailed answer in the notes from a Sefardi perspective: https://harav.org/books/mahamar_mordechay_shabat_36/#_ftnref156

Comment: There's also a lengthy Beiur haGra, for those interested: https://beta.hebrewbooks.org/tursa.aspx?a=oc_x2140 (וי"א השמים)

Comment: Similarly in Ezras Torah. "Shim'u, but if your minhag is hashamayim kis'i, do that." https://www.ezrastorah.org/calendar5781.php?page=av Seems American English standardizers have settled on that.

Comment: Is your recent edit (from Rav Drukman) relevant here? That's discussing the haftarot of consolation after 9 Av, not the haftarot of punishment before...

Comment: @JoelK you are right - I made the analogy in my mind that if there is a sequence in the seven, there must be a sequence in the 3, but I should make it explicit

Comment: @mbloch On that analogy, it's interesting that current mainstream Ashkenazi practice (in Israel at least) seems to have settled on reading Shim'u for Shabbat Rosh Chodesh Av, but not Aniya So'ara for Shabbat Rosh Chodesh Elul, reading instead Hashamayim Kis'i